# PyQt / PySide keyboard shortcut for specific widget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I'm trying to use QShortcut to set a keyboard shortcut, only for when a certain widget is focused.

I thought that by setting the parent, this would work.  For example:

```
QtGui.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence("Ctrl+Return"), self.myWidget, self.doSomething)
```

But, this is fired when ever Ctrl+Return is pressed.  I know I can do this by subclassing `QWidget` and overwriting `setShortcut`, but this seems overkill?

Is there an easier way?

(Answers can be in C++)

To Add:

I think this can be done using `QShortcutContext` http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qshortcut.html but

```
QtGui.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence("Ctrl+Return"), self.myWidget, self.doSomething, context=QtCore.Qt.WidgetShortcut)
```

doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was due to a bug in PyQt, upgrading to 4.10.3 has solved the issue and means I can use the shortcut context to get desired results.